# I have multiple radio buttons set up with multiple choices to select

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATED 3/25/20 11:20 est **

The issue I am having now is the code is not using num3 as intended.  It is set up like the rest of the code in the HTML and script.  This is the set up of my form:

```
<form name = "arrowCalc">
<table>
    <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Draw Length:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtDraw"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Spine:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="spine400" name="spineType" value="8.9"><label>400 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine350" name="spineType" value="9.8"><label>350 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine300" name="spineType" value="11.2"><label>300 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine250" name="spineType" value="12.5"><label>250 Spine</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Nock Weight:</label></td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="standardNock" name="nocType" checked="checked" value="6"><label>Standard</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="nockTurnal" name="nocType" value="21"><label>Nockturnal</label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Insert Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtInsert"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Broadhead Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtBroad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Vane Weight:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneR" name="vaneType" value="6" ><label>Rapt-X</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneD" name="vaneType" value="8"><label>DVX 8</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneF2" name="vaneType" value="7"><label>Fusion 2.1</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneF3" name="vaneType" value="7.5"><label>Fusion 3.0</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Number of Vanes:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="vanes3" name="vaneNumber" value="3"><label>3</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vanes4" name="vaneNumber" value="4"><label>4</label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="weightFormula()" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtRes"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my function:

```
function weightFormula() {
    var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, res;
    num1=Number(document.arrowCalc.txtDraw.value)-.5;
    num2=document.querySelector('input[name=spineType]:checked').value;
    num3=document.querySelector('input[name=nocType]:checked').value; 
    num4=Number(document.arrowCalc.txtInsert.value);
    num5=Number(document.arrowCalc.txtBroad.value);
    num6=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneType]:checked').value;
    num7=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneNumber]:checked').value;        
    res=(num1*num2)+num4+num5+(num6*num7)+10+num3;
    document.arrowCalc.txtRes.value=res;
}
```

With the exception as num3, all other variables are working as expected.  If I would make num3 a text input or a dropdown box, the code also works as expected.  Currently num3 will just add the value to the end of the total number.  For instance if I am expecting an answer of 775.25 and I select the Standard nock (value of 6) the answer would be 769.256.  The same thing happens when I move num3 to other spots in the res= line, it will just place the values at the end of the decimal.

```
The numbers I have been using for this are:

Draw Length (num1) = 29
Spine (num2) = 12.5 (spine250)
Nock (num3) = 6 (standard)
Insert (num4) = 175
Broadhead (num5) = 200
Vane type (num6) = 7 (Fusion 2.1)
Vane number (num7) = 4
```

As previously stated, this should equal 775.25

Comment: NaN stands for „Not a number”. In JavaScript, `+` can either do the addition or concatenate strings. If one part of the operation is of type string, JavaScript will convert the other for you. You can't multiply a string in JavaScript (likely leading to the `NaN`). My guess would be a needed conversion of `num2` into a Number. Perhaps using `parseFloat()`?

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: what calculate button?  How is the function attached as an event handler for the missing button?  Is this a syntax error perhaps `,*/ res;`

Comment: I don't see a „calculate button”. Could you share more HTML? How do you see, that „nothing happens” on a click?

Comment: please post more HTML than this, In your javascript you refer to elements we don't see in the HTML. The code you post should let us reproduce the issue

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[spineType]:checked').value`. From the `html`, `spineType` is value of attribute and not attribute. It shoud be `document.querySelector('input[name="spineType"]:checked').value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using eval()

```
  function weightFormula() {
        var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, res;
        num1=document.arrowCalc.txtDraw.value-.5+"";
        num2=document.querySelector('input[name=spineType]:checked').value;
       num3=document.querySelector('input[name=nocType]:checked').value;  /*This is part of the issue*/
        num4=document.arrowCalc.txtInsert.value;
        num5=document.arrowCalc.txtBroad.value;
        num6=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneType]:checked').value;
        num7=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneNumber]:checked').value;       
        debugger;
        res=eval(`${num1}*${num2}+${num4}+${num5}+(${num6}*${num7})+10+${num3}`);
        document.arrowCalc.txtRes.value=res;
    }
```

```js
function weightFormula() {
    var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, res;
    num1=document.arrowCalc.txtDraw.value-.5+"";
    num2=document.querySelector('input[name=spineType]:checked').value;
   num3=document.querySelector('input[name=nocType]:checked').value;  /*This is part of the issue*/
    num4=document.arrowCalc.txtInsert.value;
    num5=document.arrowCalc.txtBroad.value;
    num6=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneType]:checked').value;
    num7=document.querySelector('input[name=vaneNumber]:checked').value;       
    debugger;
    res=eval(`${num1}*${num2}+${num4}+${num5}+(${num6}*${num7})+10+${num3}`);
    document.arrowCalc.txtRes.value=res;
}
```

```html
<form name = "arrowCalc">
<table>
    <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Draw Length:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtDraw"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Spine:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="spine400" name="spineType" value="8.9"><label>400 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine350" name="spineType" value="9.8"><label>350 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine300" name="spineType" value="11.2"><label>300 Spine</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spine250" name="spineType" value="12.5"><label>250 Spine</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Nock Weight:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="standardNock" name="nocType" checked="checked" value="6"><label>Standard</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="nockTurnal" name="nocType" value="21"><label>Nockturnal</label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Insert Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtInsert"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Broadhead Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtBroad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Vane Weight:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneR" name="vaneType" value="6" ><label>Rapt-X</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneD" name="vaneType" value="8"><label>DVX 8</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneF2" name="vaneType" value="7"><label>Fusion 2.1</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vaneF3" name="vaneType" value="7.5"><label>Fusion 3.0</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Number of Vanes:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="vanes3" name="vaneNumber" value="3"><label>3</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="vanes4" name="vaneNumber" value="4"><label>4</label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="weightFormula()" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Weight:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtRes"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I have updated the original post to reflect the entire form.

Comment: please provide me the inputs and outputs for testing purpose...Example: num1 is this , num2 is this and  output value is this

Comment: I have been using:  num1=29, num2=12.5(spine250), num3=6(standardNock, num4=175, num5=200, num6=7(Fusion2.1), num7=4(vaneNumber).  These numbers will equal to 775.25 when the code works right, I have used input text boxes and drop down boxes previously and it has worked.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is correct.  It is returning the results I am expecting.